# IOS have the background service provides function like the android aidl service?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I developed a background service for android, which works by providing some interface through AIDL, so if another application wants to use these functions, it just binds to my service.
Now I want to do the same thing in IOS, i have no idea to do these in the IOS.

I want to know whether it works in IOS like android. Iff yes, which module can be used? or have another way to do this in IOS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think, is the short answer. iOS has very limited inter-process communication facilities and only a limited range of applications are able to multi-task.

The closest equivalent -- and it's not terribly close -- would be a URL scheme. Your app would "advertise" its services and other apps would switch over to your app to perform them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And if I modify my service to a local service in the application(And it almost running in the background, and provide the functions, and transport data through the function ), only this application can use it. So want to know this kind service can be implement?

Comment: If only the current app can use it, it simply becomes and singleton, maybe even just a normal class. Possibly a thread if it really needs to run continually.